# How to write data in firebase realtime database

Tags: database, firebase, authentication, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am working with firebase in html, and it shows my users in the firebase authentication. Only problem is that id don't know how to write data of some other sort. pls help bye

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: dberf.setvalue("value")

Comment: Have you tried to attach a listener to see if something goes wrong?

Comment: @AlexMamo how would it do that?

Comment: dberf.setvalue("value").addOnCompleteListener(/* ... /*). Have you found something wrong in the reponse?